# For loop does not complete inside Promise

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm trying to write a function that includes a `for` loop inside a Promise, however the loop only performs on iteration and the promise is never resolved.

My code looks like this:

```
function appendPosts() {
    return functionThatReturnsAPromise()
       .then( result => {
           return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
              var list = [];
              result.forEach( item => {
                 //do stuff to item
                 list.push(item);
              });
             resolve(list);
           });
       })
       .then( list => {
          return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
             //This loop only runs once, even when list has contains many items
          for ( var i = 0; i < list.length; i++ ) {
             document.querySelector("someSelector").appendChild( list[i] );
          }
          resolve();
       });
   });
}
```

Clearly I'm doing something wrong. Any ideas?

Thanks for your time.
- Daniel

Comment: What is purpose of `Promise` constructor within `.then()`? Why do you iterate `result` only to push `item` to an array?

Comment: I don't think it's possible that the for loop runs only one time when list has longer length. Doublecheck the iterations and list.length.

Comment: Maybe an exception occurs in the first iteration? Use [`catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch).

Comment: by the way - your code (as shown) is equivalent to https://jsfiddle.net/ms4yr8sr/

Comment: As hinted, the return value of a promise reaction handler is used to resolve the  promise returned from the `then` or `catch` call which added the handler. Returning a new promise synchronously resolved with a value instead of simply returning the value is redundant, and a bad example to follow if you read it somewhere.

Comment: @MaazSyedAdeeb is right. There was an exception thrown in the loop and I didn't have a catch block in place. guest271314 and Jaromanda X are also right that the syntax I was using was overly complicated. However simplifying the syntax didn't fix it -- catching the exception did. Thanks to everybody for their time and support.

Answer (score 0):

@MaazSyedAdeeb is right. There was an exception thrown in the loop and I didn't have a catch block in place. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The selector probably did not return a match, and so `appendChild` was called on `undefined`, triggering an exception translated to a rejected promise.

You could treat this error if in your call you add a `.catch`:

```
appendPosts().then(function () {
    console.log('all done');
}).catch(function (err) {
    console.log('error occurred: ', err);
});
```

But it should also be mentioned that you are using the [promise constructor anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it). Namely, in a `then` callback you can just return a value, and that value will become the promised value of the promise that `then` will return. So there is no need to do `new Promise()`. Instead, do this:

```
function appendPosts() {
    return functionThatReturnsAPromise().then( result => {
        // Just return the mapped array:
        return result.map( item => {
            //do stuff to item
            return item;
        }).then( list => {
            for ( var i = 0; i < list.length; i++ ) {
                // Make sure the selector will result in a match:
                document.querySelector("someSelector").appendChild( list[i] );
            }
        });
    });
}
```